# Is it possible to showing one site with 2 domains?

Tags: routes, web

My company website is `company.com` for example. and it's store is on `company.com/store`. But I want to create a copy of my store in `store.com` too. I mean if user uses either address, the address should not change like parking domains.

How can I do it and sync these to domains together? is it possible in a easy way or I must write a special code for that?

Comment: If you want literally the same site you want to read up about routing and servers. You could also just redirect from company.com/store ti store.com

Comment: @Orangesandlemons: with your method, all the users will see the `store.com` in address bar, but I wanted they see different addresses. I mean if you use `company.com/store` you see this address finally in your address bar. I don't like it changes to `store.com`.

Comment: that's only true of a redirect. worth reading up server routing if that's not what you want. (although you could potentially have just a shared database and not even go down that route)